# RootSum result manipulation/simplification

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, summation, algebraic-manipulation

Consider the sum

```
sum1 = Sum[ k/( k^7 - 2 k + 3), {k, Infinity}]
```

> ```
> -RootSum[ 2 + 5 #1 + 21 #1^2 + 35 #1^3 + 35 #1^4 + 21 #1^5 + 7 #1^6 + #1^7 &,
>           ( PolyGamma[0, -#1] + PolyGamma[0, -#1] #1)/( 5 + 42 #1 + 105 #1^2 + 140 #1^3 
>              + 105 #1^4 + 42 #1^5 + 7 #1^6)& ]
> ```

Back in the day of Mathematica 3.0 this same sum gave

```
sum2 = RootSum[( 3 - 2 #1 + #1^7) & , -(( PolyGamma[0, -#1] #1)/(-2 + 7 #1^6))& ]
```

> ```
> -RootSum[ 3 - 2 #1 + #1^7 &, ( PolyGamma[0, -#1] #1)/(-2 + 7 #1^6)& ]
> ```

They are numerically equal

```
(sum1 - sum2) // N // Chop
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

- Are the two `RootSum` expressions equivalent? and If so:
- How do I manipulate/simplify `sum1` result to the simpler form of `sum2`?
- Why is the current result more complicated?

Comment: Answering your first question: those ARE numbers, not functions. So, if their numerical value is equal ...

Answer (score 4):

`PolyGamma` was modified in version 6 (see [Summary of New Features in 6.0](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn60.html)) as well as `Sum` last modified in version 7; therefore, the results of these sums are symbolically different. Perhaps `sum1` is simpler than `sum2` with respect to internal algebraic manipulations.

To verify equivalence you can make use of symbolic functionality, e.g.

```
RootApproximant[ sum1 - sum2 ]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

This may be enforced by numerical approximations to arbitrary order, e.g.

```
N[sum1, 3000] === N[sum2, 3000]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to notice is that

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{k^7-2k+3}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k+1}{(k+1)^7-2(k+1)+3}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k+1}{k^7+7 k^6+21 k^5+35 k^4+35 k^3+21 k^2+5 k+2}
\end{align*}$$

The second thing you must know is that performing a full partial fraction decomposition on a rational function with an irreducible, high-degree denominator is not done through factoring(**!!!**), but through an implicit procedure known as Hermite reduction (see e.g. [Bronstein](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=8SAaSd89sSkC&pg=PA39)).

In particular, the important formulae in this situation are

```
RootSum[Function[k, k^7 - 2 k + 3], Function @@ {k, n/((n - k) D[k^7 - 2 k + 3, k])}]
   n/(3 - 2 n + n^7)
```

compared with

```
RootSum[Function[k, 2 + 5 k + 21 k^2 + 35 k^3 + 35 k^4 + 21 k^5 + 7 k^6 + k^7], 
        Function @@ {k, 1/((n - k)
                        D[2 + 5 k + 21 k^2 + 35 k^3 + 35 k^4 + 21 k^5 + 7 k^6 + k^7, k])}]
   1/(2 + 5 n + 21 n^2 + 35 n^3 + 35 n^4 + 21 n^5 + 7 n^6 + n^7)

RootSum[Function[k, 2 + 5 k + 21 k^2 + 35 k^3 + 35 k^4 + 21 k^5 + 7 k^6 + k^7], 
        Function @@ {k, n/((n - k)
                        D[2 + 5 k + 21 k^2 + 35 k^3 + 35 k^4 + 21 k^5 + 7 k^6 + k^7, k])}]
   n/(2 + 5 n + 21 n^2 + 35 n^3 + 35 n^4 + 21 n^5 + 7 n^6 + n^7)
```

The reason for representing them in this way is that performing the summation with rational terms is as easy as replacing the `n^j/(n - k)` factor with `-k^j PolyGamma[-k]`; thus:

```
RootSum[Function[k, k^7 - 2 k + 3], 
        Function @@ {k, k/((n - k) D[k^7 - 2 k + 3, k]) /. n -> k - 1/PolyGamma[-k]}]
   -RootSum[3 - 2 #1 + #1^7 &, (PolyGamma[0, -#1] #1)/(-2 + 7 #1^6) &]

N[%, 25] == N[Sum[k/(k^7 - 2 k + 3), {k, 0, ∞}], 25]
   True
```

while

```
RootSum[Function[k, 2 + 5 k + 21 k^2 + 35 k^3 + 35 k^4 + 21 k^5 + 7 k^6 + k^7], 
        Function @@ {k, (n + 1)/((n - k)
                     D[2 + 5 k + 21 k^2 + 35 k^3 + 35 k^4 + 21 k^5 + 7 k^6 + k^7, k]) /.
                     n -> k - 1/PolyGamma[-k]}]
   -RootSum[2 + 5 #1 + 21 #1^2 + 35 #1^3 + 35 #1^4 + 21 #1^5 + 7 #1^6 + #1^7 &,
            (-1 + PolyGamma[0, -#1] + PolyGamma[0, -#1] #1)/
            (5 + 42 #1 + 105 #1^2 + 140 #1^3 + 105 #1^4 + 42 #1^5 + 7 #1^6) &]

N[%, 25] ==
N[Sum[(k + 1)/(2 + 5 k + 21 k^2 + 35 k^3 + 35 k^4 + 21 k^5 + 7 k^6 + k^7), {k, 0, ∞}], 25]
   True
```

The observant will instantly notice a dangling constant in the numerator, but this doesn't matter because

```
RootSum[Function[k, 2 + 5 k + 21 k^2 + 35 k^3 + 35 k^4 + 21 k^5 + 7 k^6 + k^7], 
        Function @@ {k, 1/D[2 + 5 k + 21 k^2 + 35 k^3 + 35 k^4 + 21 k^5 + 7 k^6 + k^7, k]}]
   0
```

(Exercise: **why?**)

---

An analogous discussion could be done for the case of integrating a rational function, with summation being replaced by integration, and the digamma function being replaced by a logarithm.